# React + Redux too many re-renders of mapped components with another API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm trying to make a website similar to MyAnimeList(MAL) using Jikan, an unofficial MAL API with React and Redux. In the home page of the app, there is a section for promotional videos of popular anime which displays the video thumbnails and I wanted to recreate it.

here's a sample of what I want to achieve: [sample of promotional video section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsyd3.png)

Based on the API docs, here is how I get the popular anime:

```
const base_url = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3/";
```

```
export const get_popular_anime = () =>`${base_url}search/anime?q&order_by=score&sort=desc`;
```

and here is how I get the promotional videos:

```
export const get_promos = (anime_id) => `${base_url}anime/${anime_id}/videos`;
```

To fetch the data, I have an action and reducer for getting the animes and for getting anime details such as promos, news, etc.

**animeReducer.js**

```
const initState = {
  New: [],
  popular: [],
  spring: [],
  winter: [],
  summer: [],
  fall: [],
};

const animeReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_ANIME":
      return {
        ...state,
        New: action.payload.New,
        popular: action.payload.popular,
        spring: action.payload.spring,
        winter: action.payload.winter,
        summer: action.payload.summer,
        fall: action.payload.fall,
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default animeReducer;
```

**animeAction.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  get_new_anime,
  get_popular_anime,
  get_spring_anime,
  get_winter_anime,
  get_summer_anime,
  get_fall_anime,
} from "../api";



export const loadAnime = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const newData = await axios.get(get_new_anime());
  const popularData = await axios.get(get_popular_anime());
  const springData = await axios.get(get_spring_anime());
  const winterData = await axios.get(get_winter_anime());
  const summerData = await axios.get(get_summer_anime());
  const fallData = await axios.get(get_fall_anime());

  dispatch({
    type: "GET_ANIME",
    payload: {
      New: newData.data.results,
      popular: popularData.data.results,
      spring: springData.data.anime,
      winter: winterData.data.anime,
      summer: summerData.data.anime,
      fall: fallData.data.anime,
    },
  });
};
```

detailReducer.js

```
const initState = {
  promo: [],
  news: [],
  isLoading: true,
};

const detailReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_DETAIL":
      return {
        ...state,

        promo: action.payload.promo,
        news: action.payload.news,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case "LOADING_DETAIL":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }
};

export default detailReducer;
```

detailAction.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { get_anime_details, get_promos, get_news } from "../api";

export const loadDetail = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "LOADING_DETAIL",
  });

  const detailData = await axios.get(get_anime_details(id));
  const promoData = await axios.get(get_promos(id));
  const news = await axios.get(get_news(id));

  dispatch({
    type: "GET_DETAIL",
    payload: {
      promo: promoData.data.promo,
      news: news.data.articles,
    },
  });
};
```

In my Home.js file, here is how I map the popular anime:

```
 <Promotionals>
        {popular
          .filter((anime, show) => show < 4)
          .map((anime) => (
            <Promo id={anime.mal_id} key={anime.mal_id}></Promo>
          ))}
      </Promotionals>
```

In my Promo component, I dispatched loadDetail() from detailAction.js for each mapped promo component to get the thumbnails, but I end up re-rendering all of the promo components which gives me a "Too many re-renders" error.

As a workaround for debugging, I put an onClick handler for each promo component to load the thumbnail.

```
const Promo = ({ thumbnail, id }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loadDetailHandler = () => {
    // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    dispatch(loadDetail(id));
    console.log(id);
  };

 const {promo, isLoading} = useSelector((state) => state.details);

return(
 <PromoBox
      onClick={wrappedOnClick}
      style={
        !isLoading
          ? { backgroundImage: `url("${promo[0].image_url}")` }
          : { backgroundImage: "none" }
      }
      //src={`"${promo[0].image_url}"`}
    ></PromoBox>
)
```

here's a screenshot of the result if a promo is clicked: [promo components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kX4D.png)

and so, I need help as to how I can load the thumbnails with each individual promo and avoid re-rendering, or if there is a better approach for what I want to achieve.

**UPDATE**

With the solutions provided by @Al Avery and @phry, I was able to solve the too many re-renders error. My current problem now is loading the corresponding thumbnail and promo data for each promo component. The promo components still show the same thumbnail for all components, just like the screenshot of the result I provided. I thought about combining the promo data from each state and just map it to the components, but I still don't have an idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```js
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
```

in a reducer will lead to that reducer's state being a new object on every action dispatched - and also on every component relying on that state being rerendered on every action dispatched. In the default case (or anytime nothing is changing), you should not create a new state.
Do

```js
    default:
      return state
```

instead.

There might be more problems, but without you sharing your `useSelector` calls or `mapStateToProps` functions we won't be able to comment on those.

Comment: I only have a useSelector call in the Promo component, which is this: `const {promo, isLoading} = useSelector((state) => state.details);`

Comment: That should be `const promo = useSelector(state => state.details.promo); const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.details.isLoading);` instead as otherwise every other change of `state.details` would also trigger a re-render.
And as I explained in my answer, `state.details` is ALWAYS changing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the original `Promo` component, from before you were debugging?  Specifically, I don't see where the `loadDetailHandler` method is getting called.

If I had to guess, the issue isn't actually related to the mapping and would still occur with even a single Promo component.  There's a good chance that what is happening is that (1) the Promo component mounts and calls `loadDetailHandler` (again, can't really know this without seeing the original code), (2) gets a new thumbnail prop and rerenders (3) calls `loadDetailHandler` again on rerender (4) gets a new thumbnail prop and rerenders (5) on and on and on.

Comment: Before I debugged, it was basically the same, without the `loadDetailHandler` and I was just dispatching the `loadDetail(id)`. I just made the `loadDetailHandler()` for onClick purposes. And yes, I believe you are correct with your guess.

Comment: cool, in that case this is exactly what the `useEffect` hook is for.  Should do
`useEffect(() => loadDetail(id), [id])`, which is to say, call loadDetail only when a new id is received, which should be a single time, on mount.  If this is the answer please mark it as such :)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed and solved the too many re-renders error. However, I still have a problem of rendering the corresponding thumbnail for each promo. It still shows the same thumbnail for all the promo components, just like the screenshot result I posted in the question, where instead of rendering the clicked promo, the last promo loaded renders to all components. I think I'm missing something really simple to fix this.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the reducer.  You only have a single promo field in the state.  That means that field will get overwritten every time loadDetail is called, and all the Promo components will get the incorrectly overwritten data.  You might want to make the reducer key the promos by some kind of id.  Then you should change the Promo components to only get new thumbnail if the promo under their id has changed.  I haven't used redux in a long time, but in the past this would be done with mapStateToProps.